# dimension of the vector space using matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $C$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix. Let $W$ be the vector space spanned by $\{I, C, C^2, \ldots C^{2n}\}$. The dimension of the vector space $W$ is
>
> $
> 1.\ 2n \hspace{4cm} 2.\ \text{at most}\ n\\
> 3.\ n^2 \hspace{4cm} 4.\ \text{at most}\ 2n
> $

Can we conclude that matrix becomes nilpotent? How come an arbitrary matrix becomes nilpotent?

Answer is b,d. How come two solutions are possible?

Comment: Why does anything become nilpotent? Nobody is saying any powers become $0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells you something about this topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: where on the wikipedia page should I look?

Comment: @larry Sort of... like... the whole page...?

Comment: You mean everything on the entire page answers the OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that $1$ and $3$ are not the case by considering the $0$ matrix. So now you need to rule out one of $2$ or $4$. Obviously if you find an example that has dimension greater than $n$ then $2$ is not true, but that might prove difficult. To show that $4$ is not true, consider the characteristic polynomial of $C$ and specifically, what is the degree of such a polynomial in terms of $n$, and what does the Cayley-Hamilton theorem tell you about linear combinations of powers of $C$?

Comment: Point 2. implies 4.

Comment: You're right @Marc, but I'm interpreting the question as saying 'at most $n$/$2n$ *and is attainable*' as otherwise there are more than one answer.

Comment: I don't understand how point 2 implies point 4? Can you please explain a little bit more.

Comment: If $k\leq n$ for non-negative $n$ then $k\leq 2n$.